# onBlur dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making search input with dropdown. The problem is with onBlur. How to ignore my dropdown in onBlur? when I click on Input, dropdown appears with onClick, when I click somewhere else it disappears. The problem is that I click on dropdown it disappears too.
Here is my code and sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mccarthy-37ue3?file=/src/components/test.js)

```
<input
  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-gray-300 focus:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3"
  value={filter.mark}
  onChange={onChange}
  name="mark"
  id="mark"
  onClick={() => setDropdown(true)}
  onBlur={() => setDropdown(false)}
  placeholder="Выберите бренд"
  tabIndex={1}
/>
```

Dropdown

```
<div
  className="py-1"
  role="menu"
  aria-orientation="vertical"
  aria-labelledby="options-menu"
  name="mark"
>
  {CarMarkList.map((car) => {
    if (filter.mark !== 0) {
      if (
        car.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.mark.toLowerCase()) ||
        car.name_rus.toLowerCase().includes(filter.mark.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return (
          <div
            key={car.name}
            onClick={dropdownChange}
            id="mark"
            value={filter.mark}
            className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
          >
            {car.name}
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
    return (
      <div
        key={car.name}
        onClick={dropdownChange}
        id="mark"
        value={filter.mark}
        className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
      >
        {car.name}
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes sense since your dropdown is outside your input, so when you click on it, it in fact removes focus from the input.

Your best solution here would be to wrap both of them in a div (or whatever else) and close the dropdown when an option is selected, or when clicked outside that div. Here's a CodeSandbox I made:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-bash-og2mq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this completely disregards non mouse users. Tabbing won't work, since you close the dropdown not when focus is lost, but when clicking. So while it works you probably shouldn't use it for projects others are actually supposed to use (since tab accessabilty in forms is a default functionality that can be expeceted)